# How can I make VIM a full fledged IDE

Tags: 11.04, development

How could I make VIM a full fledged IDE by using different supported plugins for YUI, JQuery and git integration etc.

Comment: IDE is a loosely defined term. There's no real set of features that makes a program into an IDE. Jon Skeet [had some ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide/208221#208221) about what might make a good IDE, but really, it's what you find useful in programming that determines it. So without knowing what features you're looking for, it's hard to help. Also, this would be more appropriate for the [UNIX and Linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps the [programmer's stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @root45: never seeing you on unix.stackexchange.com suggesting to better ask on ask.ubuntu.com :)

Answer (score 1):

First of set your `$HOME/.vimrc` to follow specific pattern. Mine is something like this:

```
" (sw)shiftwidth: how many columns text is indented with reindent operations
" (sts)softtabstop: how many columns vim uses when you hit tab
" (ts)tabstop: how many columns a tab counts for
set ts=4 sw=4 sts=2

" expandtab: appropriate number of spaces in insert mode
set expandtab

" theme and colors
set t_Co=256
colorscheme desert

" Prevents keeping of backup after overwriting the file
set nobk

" To see line numbers on the left
set number

" autocomplete parenthesis, brackets and braces
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>

" Syntax highlighting on
syntax on

" share windows clipboard
set clipboard+=unnamed

" Hightlight the curent column
set cursorcolumn

" Hightlight the current line
set cursorline
```

I recommend going through [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE). 
Some of the scripts that I recommend are:

[NerdTREE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)

[taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)(Requires `exuberant-ctags`)

[bufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42)

[snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)

As for your personal needs. You should search for suitable script [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php) and follow instructions.

Comment: Wirth to say, `vim` is required, instead of the default `vim-tiny` installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Or, run vim inside of [`pida`](http://pida.co.uk/).